# i am Hosting my MERN stack Application on shared hosting but getting this error "Can't acquire lock for an app:"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, web-hosting

i want to host MERN stack application on shared hosting but when i click RUN NPM INSTALL or try to stop my app it give me the errror "Can't acquire lock for an app:"[image]

Comment: Would be better if you can provide more details, like which hosting services are you using to deploy your app

Comment: i am using hostbest for my hosting

Answer (score 0):

Deleting .lock file from /home/nodevenv/ solved the issue for me